# How to delete an entry from a Record in typescript,based on the Id

Tags: reactjs, typescript, frontend

I have a Main.tsx file where i have a Record ,personList,with key as PersonId and value as PersonInfo,i want to delete a particular entry from personList,based on Id provided.Below is my code:

```
interface PersonInfo{
FirstName:string;
SecondName:string;
Age:string;
}

const [personList,setPersonList] = useState<Record<string,PersonInfo>>({});

//For inserting entry
const Create = () => {

      setPersonList((oldList)=>{
        return {
          ...oldList,[PersonId]:PersonDescription  //PersonDescription is of type PersonInfo
        }
      });
};

const Delete = () => {

    const newPersonList :Record<string,PersonInfo>=
    personList.filter()//Here i want to delete the entry based on personId

    setPersonList(newPersonList);
 };
```

Comment: based on the actual shape of `Record`, if you really want to use `Array.prototype.filter`, then something like `Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(personList).filter(([k, v]) => k !== personId))`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you're already assigning the keys of your object to the `personId` you can just do:

```js
const Delete = (id: string): void => {
    const filteredPersonList: Record<string,PersonInfo> = {}
    for(let key in personList){
        if(key !== id){
            filteredPersonList[key] = personList[key]
        }
    }
    setPersonList(filteredPersonList)
}
```

Answer (score 15):

What about use `delete` keyword?

```
delete personList[personId];
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I recommend against rhetoric questions in answers. They risk being misunderstood as not an answer at all. You are trying to answer the question at the top of this page, aren't you? Otherwise please delete this post.

Comment: This answer doesn't work for the specific context of the question, which is updating the state of a React component. The question title is somewhat misleading. What OP actually wants to do is create a modified copy of the record without mutating the original.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the context (i.e. updating React state) and your code sample, what you actually want to do is create a modified copy of the record without mutating the original.

```
const deletePerson = (personId: string): void => {
    // first create a shallow copy of the old record.
    const newList = {...personList};
    // now delete the entry from the new record
    delete newList[personId];
    setPersonList(newList)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Eslint complains with @ehutchllew answer:

```
  40:7  error  for..in loops iterate over the entire prototype chain, which is virtually never what you want. Use Object.{keys,values,entries}, and iterate over the resulting array  no-restricted-syntax
  40:7  error  The body of a for-in should be wrapped in an if statement to filter unwanted properties from the prototype                                                             guard-for-in
```

So using the suggested `Object.{keys,values,entries}`, it becomes:

```js
const Delete = (id: string): void => {
  const filteredPersonList: Record<string, PersonInfo> = {};
  Object.keys(personList).forEach((key) => {
    if (key !== id) {
      filteredPersonList[key] = personList[key];
    }
  });
  setPersonList(filteredPersonList);
};
```